# Android WebView: where are connections to bc.googleusercontent.com coming from?

Tags: android, webview

My app opens a WebView, which in turn loads a simple page from my remote host.  Recently I've been trying to minimise the amount of data usage, by maximising cache usage, and have started using a network connections monitor app like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antispycell.connmonitor) and [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.bananenfisch.connectionlistlite) to check what connections are actually being made by my app (and others).

These are showing that, as well as a connection being made to the host when the webview loads, a connection is also being made to `nnn.n.nnn.nn.bc.googleusercontent.com`.  The first of the above apps resolves this to an admin address of Google Inc.

But I have no idea why this connection is being made.  My webpage does not have any google-related tracking code or anything like that, has no links to adverts, nothing at all along those lines.  And the Android app itself, that loads the WebView, likewise does not at any point try to fetch "user content" from `googleusercontent.com`.

I would post some code, but since I have no idea where this call is initiated from, I wouldn't know what to show.  I would also say that I have noticed on my phone that occasionally a full-page advert will pop up, and I have no idea where it's coming from... but it doesn't happen at the same time as these calls to `googleusercontent.com`.

Any insight on this would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I figured it out.  My web page makes a call to my node.js app running on Cloud 9... I think that the mysterious `nnn.n.nnn.nn.bc.googleusercontent.com` must just be where the node app is being hosted.  When I call this page from my production app (where the node app is running on heroku) I get a call to a different yet similarly mysterious-looking address: `xxxxxxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`... so that must be where the heroku node app is hosted.